# Show copied text in a small window android

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android. 
My question is:
Whenever a user copy something without opening the app i want to show the word into a small window which the user can move the window wherever they want.
I have read many article about listening the clipboard manager.I understand that.
But problem is i dont know how to show this into a small window which can be moved anywhere without opening the main app.
I have searched a lot but cant find anything.
Please suggestion me some article or the way to achieve my goal.

Here is the link which is similar to my goal .
[LINK](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/qviADz9egjUmKk6mBTg6TL9wgbs2JPW2TWL2ynyuC-k8gBPUaoL8prOl7_g7AMtvHQI=h900-rw)

Comment: The link is to a RIFF file? Seems dodgy to me.

Comment: @Tigger It's an image file hosted by Google. Not sure where you're seeing another file type.

Comment: `file unnamed.webp` returns `unnamed.webp: RIFF (little-endian) data`. Maybe just include the image or link to a JPG / PNG instead? Edit: OK, the .webp format is not support on Firefox. I guess that is why it seemed dodgy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service as Facebook Messenger has done its Chat Heads. Look for example [here](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/)